# Erro no jinja2: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'

Tags: python, aplicação-web, flask, jinja2

Meu código está gerando um erro de " unexpected '%' ", sendo que todos os símbolos estão devidamente corretos.

Tenho uma rota para mostrar os CNPJs de empresas numa lista, segue função da listagem abaixo:

```
@app.route("/list/company")
def listCompany():
    companies = Company.query.all()

    return render_template("listCompany.html", companies = companies)
```

Segue abaixo o trecho HTML da página de listagem.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
    </tr>
    {{% for companie in companies %}}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ companies._id }} </td>
        <td> {{ companies.cnpj }} </td>
    </tr>
    {{% endfor %}}
</table>
```

Esse código me gera o erro:

**jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tags for, estão erradas.

```py
{% for companie in companies %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!!!!!!

Comment: Por nada! ;-) Acontece mesmo, as vezes passa despercebido.